# How can I run my Qt function after a thread has finished?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qtconcurrent

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QFuture<int> future = QtConcurrent::run(identify);  //Thread1
    if (future.isFinished())
    {
       //DoSomething();    
    }
}
```

I have this code. I want to run the `DoSomething()` function after the identify function finished running. Is it possible?

Comment: I've tried that and the problem is that the GUI remains unresponsive until the thread is finished.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can pass the `QFuture` object to a [`QFutureWatcher`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfuturewatcher.html) and connect its `finished()` signal to the function or slot `DoSomething()`.

For example:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QFuture<int> future = QtConcurrent::run(identify); //Thread1
    QFutureWatcher<int> *watcher = new QFutureWatcher<int>(this);
           connect(watcher, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(doSomething()));
    // delete the watcher when finished too
     connect(watcher, SIGNAL(finished()), watcher, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    watcher->setFuture(future);
}

void MainWindow::DoSomething() // slot or ordinary function
{
    // ...
}
```

Or you could use a nested event loop to keep the GUI responsive and have everything inside the same function:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QFuture<int> future = QtConcurrent::run(identify);  //Thread1
    QFutureWatcher<int> watcher;
    QEventLoop loop;
    // QueuedConnection is necessary in case the signal finished is emitted before the loop starts (if the task is already finished when setFuture is called)
    connect(&watcher, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()),  Qt::QueuedConnection); 
    watcher.setFuture(future);
    loop.exec();

    DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: connect(&watcher, SIGNAL(finished()), &myObject, SLOT(handleFinished()));
I have a question what do I write instead of &myObject and handleFinished?

Comment: @NemethAttila I added 2 examples.

Comment: Thank you, the second example does exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @NemethAttila Be careful with local event loops. Best is to avoid them if possible.

Comment: Why should I avoid event loops?

Comment: @NemethAttila Because a lot can happen while events are processed. For example, your `this` object might be deleted.

Comment: I've solved my problem without using event loops, and thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

I like this call layout.

```
auto watcher = new QFutureWatcher<int>(this);
connect(watcher, &QFutureWatcher<int>::finished,
    [watcher, this] ()
{
    watcher->deleteLater();
    auto res = watcher->result();
    // ...
});

watcher->setFuture(QtConcurrent::run(identify, param1, param2));
```